# How do I properly make my batch game self check for updates on other people's computers and download them if needed?

Tags: batch-file, self-updating

I am making a game with batch and am sharing it with my friend.

I didn't want to keep sending him all of the files whenever I updated so I added the wget feature to both of our computers so I can input a link and it will download the file\folder corresponding to it.

So when my game starts up, it would download a batch file from my mediafire that I would update to know what the newest version is. My game would then call that file after it has downloaded and it would set the variable `nwstvrsn` (newest version) to equal the newest version number of the game. If the version number didn't match my friend's current version number, then the game would use the wget feature to download a batch file from my mediafire that I would edit every time I updated the game to download the needed files from my mediafire.

The problem is that, whenever I change a file on my mediafire, it changes the download link to it. Which means that there is no way to auto-download it. (At least no way that I know of.) Is there any website that won't change the download link to my file if I edit it? Or is there a less complicated way to make my program self-check for updates and download them if needed?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is using a driect link host like dropbox. You have to setup the public folder and put there the batch files with the version number in the file name. For example MyGame1.2.bat. And you have to also upload a txt file with the latest version number in it (for example newversion.txt with in it 1.1 written). Then in the code you have to do this

```
#setting current version
set /p version=1.0
#checking latest version
wget.exe --no-check-certificate https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/YOURUSERNUMBER/newversion.txt
set /p nwstvrsn=<newversion.txt
set nwstvrsn=%nwstvrsn: =%
if %version% lss %nwstvrsn% goto newupdateavailable
if %version%==%nwstvrsn% goto noupdateavailable

:newupdateavailable
#downloading new version if it exists
echo Downloading Update
wget.exe --no-check-certificate https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/YOURUSERNUMBER/MyGame%nwstvrsn%.bat

:noupdateavailable
echo No Update Available
```

And you should have the latest file downloaded.

Answer (score 0):

Use a dropbox public folder. The URL doesn't change.

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/12345678/